# Cake bake don't generate auto rules

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm newbie in cakephp and i'm generating model's code with bake. But the code generated dont give with a array with auto validations. why not? My fields are not null, an id, an title and an content fields. Sorry for my bad english, and thanks very much.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: First of, what version of cake are you using? 3? If it is, it will generate validation rules for you... to a certain degree. Secondly, cake has a pages controller that ships with it, so you should abstain from creating tables with that name

Comment: Hi! I'm using version 2.6.3. I cannot have a model with name "Page"? I  thought that was recommended in the documentation.

Comment: You can certainly create a Page Model. I just suggested not using it as a start because Cake uses it as the default for homepage. It is up to you. If you are new to CakePHP, I would strongly suggest you download and start using CakePHP 3.x . Here is the book http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html .. just follow instructions in that document to install it. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Automatically the cakephp bake doesn't create validation rules for your models. However it provides an interactive shell to create the models and also the validation rules and/or relationships.
More info in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html)